# SyntaxError trying to use Select in Selenium for python

Tags: python, select, selenium

Here are the relevant lines of my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("TimecardPeriodList")
select.select_by_index(5)
```

I'm receiving an Invalid Syntax error message on the last line, with the arrow pointing at the "t" in the first "select". (this is my first post so I can't attach images yet).

Based on the threads I've seen for using select in selenium, I'm doing this correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is missing a closing parenthesis.

```
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("TimecardPeriodList"))
                                                                  ^
```