# Finding element by a variable

Tags: python, string, selenium

I'm trying to select an element from a dropdown list. The element is defined by its value, which is a date. For this example, let's say the date that I'm trying to select is today. The element's value is "2014/10/06"

I have defined a variable "oracledate" which links to a field with "2014/10/06".
I know it is defining correctly because when I print(oracledate) it appears 2014/10/06.

However, the following code does not work:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(@value, oracledate)]").click()
```

When I hardcode, it works properly:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(@value, '2014/10/04')]").click()
```

Why isn't it working when I try to find the element using the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> oracledata = '2014/10/04'
>>> "//option[contains(@value, '{}')]".format(oracledata)
"//option[contains(@value, '2014/10/04')]"
```

or [`%` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
>>> "//option[contains(@value, '%s')]" % oracledata
"//option[contains(@value, '2014/10/04')]"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. when i try either of those, i get errors saying that the element the xpath couldn't be found. i think i may be formatting incorrectly? because i think they way i have it now, the browser is trying to find an element with "%s" in the value. sorry, this is one of my first times using python...

Comment: also, i should mention that "oracledate" is already a string variable

Comment: @sdailey814, Did you use `%` operator as I mentioned in the answer?  `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(@value, '%s')]" % oracledata).click()`

Comment: it worked when I copied and pasted that. i must have mistyped something. Thanks! I'll mark as answered when i can

Comment: @sdailey814, Could you accept this answer, too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144747 ;)